# Concatenate bigint values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns:

- `PersonId uniqueidentifier` -- key
- `DeviceId uniqueidentifier` -- key
- `Counter bigint`

The `counter` comes in ascending value but sometimes has gaps. An example of the counter values is `(1,2,3,1000,10000,10001,10002,...)`. The counter value is saved one at a time. If I insert one row per counter value, the table gets big very fast. I must keep the last 1000 counter values and can delete early values.

Is it possible to concatenate the counter values into 1 or a few rows in a `varbinary(8000)` type, and remove early values at the beginning of the binary as part of the insert operation? I would like help in writing this query. I prefer not to use `varchar` because each character would take up 2 bytes. There may be better way than I can envision. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `varchar` does **NOT** take 2 bytes per character - that would be `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to do that versus using a table with PersonID, DeviceID, Counter, and allow only a certain number of Counters per PersonID and DeviceID pair?

If your goal is to save space, remember that varbinary(8000) is going to reserve 8000 bytes, allowing 1000 bigint values maximum, with no consideration of how many counters you have.

How likely is it that most of these PersonID and DeviceID pair will have 1000 counters?

In the end, you are just making it more complicated for yourself and harder to maintain by future employees but are you really saving space?

You are also going to have to add some transaction process which will take away more of your server's resources.

But to answer your question strictly: yes, it is possible. I guess a trigger or a process at the end of a sproc could handle what you are trying to do.

Comment: The consensus is not to do with varbinary.  I think that is the right answer.  Thanks.

Comment: "varbinary(8000) is going to reserve 8000 bytes" certainly not: It only takes as much space as there is data in contrast to binary(8000).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can choose an in-between solution: Make each row have 10 or so columns of type bigint. That will cut the number of rows by ten and reduce per-row overhead by 10x also. Maybe that is enough for you.

Comment: Your suggestion is a better solution, but the logic is still complicated with multi columns of counters. Thanks.